# When I turn on my MacBook Pro, I see the Apple logo and the progress bar but then it turns off

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

When I switch on my MacBook Pro 2011, I see the Apple logo with progress bar but before it enters the next screen it turns off. Why?

Comment: Does your computer actually turn off and stay off, or does it keep restarting at the same point?

Comment: Yes. it will gonna turn off. and I have to press power button again.

Comment: but battery indicator doesn't response.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add what version of macOS you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting is a process of elimination and can take quite some time. This means trying various things and reporting back with the results in order to try and get to the bottom of your problem.

**Apple Hardware Test / Apple Diagnostics**

The first thing to try is running Apple's built-in hardware diagnostics. To do this:

1. Ensure your MacBook Pro is connected to AC power
2. Start your computer
3. Immediately press and hold down the <kbd>D</kbd> key **before** the grey screen appear
4. When the icon appears on the screen let go of the <kbd>D</kbd> key
5. Select your language and click the right arrow
6. Select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox
7. Click the Test button
8. Take a note of the results that appear in the bottom-right window

Report back with your results.

**NOTE:** If holding down the <kbd>D</kbd> key doesn't work, you can also try holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys during startup to try and run the diagnostics test via the internet.

Comment: Thanks it is worked. and I could see, there is no any hardware problem. but, in addition I checkout Hardware Profiles > Power. and I could see then the battery capacity shows 0%. so this result has based on this problem? because, I gave the command to RESTART on that screen but, the later problem makes again. again it went to permanent shut down.